# GNU nano, Path: bad adress

Tags: python, path, nano

I'm new to the programming, got stuck with creating a program in Nano facing problem on the screenshot. What did I do wrong?
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbvzR.png)

Comment: Specify the filename, please.

Comment: it is hello.py . Trying to get Hello world work